# Variable not getting set by select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an issue where a variable is not getting set by a select statement.

The select joins a table variable @contracts (which is used to control a loop) and then joins to the real contract and contract line tables.

my select is:

```
select top 1 
        @contract_id = c.contract_id 
        , @account = ch.account
        , @service = cl.service
        , @model = cl.model
        , @serial = cl.serial
        , @contract = ch.contract
    from 
        @contracts c
        inner join contractline cl on c.contract_id = cl.contract_id
        inner join contractheader ch on cl.contract = ch.contract
    where
        cl.contract_id = @contract_id
```

But when I do a select @contract_id say i get a `NULL` back, as do all my variables.

I have done a simple `select * from @contracts c inner join contractline cl on c.contract_id = cl.contract_id inner join contractheader ch on cl.contract = ch.contract` and this returns exactly 1 line with the values in all the correct places, no nulls in the selected values.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you post a little more code, e.g. where you access the variable.  Are you also sure that there is a line when you include the where clause in your second select statement?

Comment: does the `@contract_id` have an initial value, because you are using it in the where clause..

Comment: That's exactly it, the where clause shouldn't be there.  Silly mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your `WHERE` clause could be stopping the row from returning.  You mentioned you've tested the same `SELECT` without setting variable, but the code you listed doesn't include this `WHERE` - so its not the same.

Test your `SELECT` with the `WHERE` in place, with dummy values (likely `NULL`) and review.  It simply sounds like its not returning a result.

Comment: Wood for trees.  I was so busy looking for something complex when it was a simple silly error.

Removed the where and magic, works perfectly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `@contract_id` in the select statement but then also using it in the where clause. I would have thought that `@contract_id` will be `null`?